# Is there any negative effect of making pipeline output workers equal to pipeline workers in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

**Note**: I have only elasticsearch in output plugin. In input plugin, there can be a maximum of 30 inputs (one input for each file). There are few filters in the filter plugin.

I ran the following test scenarios, and got unexpected results (mentioned at the end)

**Test Scenarios**:

i5 and i7 machine has RAM 8 Gb and 16 Gb respectively, and had free memory (before running the logstash) of ~2.5-3Gb and ~9Gb respectively.

Logs used in following scenarios were same and had size of ~1Gb.

1)

**Machine**: i5 (total cores 4)

**Config**: (Default values) *pipeline.workers*=4 and *pipeline.output.workers*=1

**Result**: there were no errors/warnings logged by logstash.

**Total time** to process the logs : ~30 minutes

2)

**Machine**: i7 (total cores 8)

**Config**: (Default values) *pipeline.workers*=8 and *pipeline.output.workers*=1

**Result**: there seemed to be a load on ES since there were read time out errors in logstash log.

3)

**Machine**: i7 (total cores 8)

**Config**: (custom values) *pipeline.workers*=4 and *pipeline.output.workers*=1 / 2 / 3 (increased the ow by 1 each time)

**Result**: there seemed to be a load on ES in each scenario since there were read time out errors in logstash log.

4)

**Machine**: i7 (total cores 8)

**Config**: (Custom values) *pipeline.workers*=4 and *pipeline.output.workers*=4

**Result**: there were no errors/warnings logged by logstash but total time taken was increased by ~20 minutes as compared to scenario 1.

**Total time**: ~50 minutes

I have following **questions** in mind:

1) Is there any negative effect of making pipeline output workers equal to pipeline workers in logstash ?

2) If we compare case scenarios 1 and 4, why is there increase in total time??? Logs should have been processed faster on i7 machine as compared to i5 machine.

3) What can be done to get the same performance (or better performance) on both the machines ?? (i.e. for 1Gb logs, total processing time <= ~30 minutes)

Comment: Just to be clear about your test, you use the same data on input right? Do you remove the data between each test? Also the longer time between case 1 and 4 couldn't be due to different jvm settings? Another point is that the worker settings seem deprecated, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-workers

Comment: Yes, same data was used. Other settings were left untouched i.e. I used the default settings of Elastic search and logstash. The link you posted is about the _worker_ setting in output plugin which is deprecated , whereas I am talking about _pipeline.output.workers_ and _pipeline.workers_ settings which is mentioned in config file of logstash. You may refer the link: [logstash-settings-file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html)

Comment: Good point about the workers, you should have a look at this article then: https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-history-of-logstash-output-workers    Also did you monitor resources (CPU, I/O, memory) during the tests, because if there is no resource starvation, then increasing them won't change a lot of things (see Amdhal's law for instance).  Given the history with output workers, what version of Logstash are you running?

Comment: On i5 machine, CPU and memory were properly utilized (i.e. CPU ~90-100% and memory ~80-90%), whereas on i7 machine, the resources could have been utilized better. But the question is , shouldn't i7 have worked (atleast) equal to that of i5 machine (case scenario 4). How I am gonna reduce the time to ~30 min on i7 if I do not tinker with the settings of _pipeline.output.workers_ and also avoid the read timeout errors of logstash?. I am using the lastest versions, logstash-5.2.2 and elasticsearch-5.2.2.

Comment: And the Elasticsearch node is hosted locally or on a distant server? If it is locally hosted, there might have been side effects, if it is distant, are you certain you're the only one accessing it during your tests?

Comment: Elasticsearch was hosted locally. What side effects are you talking about? No one was accessing the database other than me.

Comment: Depending how swapiness, virtual memory,  (possibly different environment variables), the memory lock enable or not. A lot of possibly different environment settings can influence the behavior of Elasticsearch. Also I would be curious as what were the exact errors output from Elastic during tests 2 and 3

Comment: Errors were something like this:            [logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Marking url as dead. {:reason=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9200][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out", :url=>#<URI::HTTP:0x58ad045b URL:http://localhost:9200>, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9200][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}